# Hail Our Information Technology Overlords

Tags: wordplay

Woe unto the people hiding their secrets in the source code.

> Immediately upon taking over the company, the Information Technology people exactingly went over the source code.

What saying is hidden in this sentence?

Hint the First:

> After manipulation, usage of homophones occurs, and the hidden saying is shorter than this sentence.

Hint the Second:

> Starting with words which seem forced into the sentence is probably a strong technique. The final phrase is 5 words long.

Comment: Great, nothing in the post's source. Welp, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I assume that homophones are used *after* synonyms, yes?

Comment: Correct assumption, I will update my hint to be more accurately informative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to guess:

> When it rains it pours

Or, in "other words"

> When IT reigns, IT pores.
> The IT department now "reigns" over the company, and thus "pores" over the source code.

Nice puzzle!

Comment: I am a little salty you got this so fast after the hint: http://www.adslogans.co.uk/site/media/.gallery/main8427.jpg

Comment: Well, to be honest, I only just saw the puzzle this morning. Actually, your second hint was not what helped, it was the first hint plus Ian MacDonald mentioning synonyms. Once I got "pore", the rest came pretty quickly.

Comment: Cool, I would have been distraught if I over hinted.